# Boot menu options

Tags: linux, debian, kali-linux

I am using a kali linux, debian derived, 1.0.9  on Usb drive with encrypted partition.

Where i find the grub menu (i think kali use Grub) and the options like:

```
.linux /live/vmlinuz boot=live persistent=enctyptsetup persistence-encryption=lu.linux 
/live/vmlinuz boot=live persistent=enctyptsetup persistence-encryption=luks noconfig=sudo username=root hostname=kali persistence initrd=/live/initrd.img
```

Into /boot/ I don't have grub folder

I did a grep but i found nothing

Comment: I have "Kali Live" partition with EFI/BOOT Folder, can i modify that and save it?

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file:

```
/etc/default/grub
```

then run in terminal to apply changes or update /boot/grub/grub.cfg

```
update-grub
```

Hope this help

Comment: What does this do and how will it help?